# How can i convert this string to array?

Tags: php, regex, arrays

I am stucked with converting the string of specific format to array. Spliting the string using `explode` doesn't seems to be the right approach and i am not so good with regular expressions. So my question is how can i convert the following string to array?

Current format of the string

```
maxWidth: 800,
openEffect: elastic,    
closeEffect: elastic,
helpers : {
       title : {
             type: outside
           },
       thumbs : {
              width  : 50,
              height : 50
            }
      }
```

Desired Array

```
array(
  'maxWidth' => 800,
  'openEffect' => 'elastic',
  'closeEffect' => 'elastic',
  'helpers' => array(
               'title' => array('type' => 'outside'),
               'thumbs' => array('width' => 50, 'height' => 50)
             )
)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT BASED ON RESPONSES:**

The string looks like a JSON but it is not a JSON. Its just a string input from user in that format. The input will be from normal user so i want to keep it simple. There is minimum chance that the normal user will enter a valid JSON.

Comment: Where does the format come from?

Comment: IMO, if it's not any kind of 'public' format (like YAML or JSON for example), you will have to roll out your own parser. If you need to do that, regex is not always the best tool for the job. Example of approach: http://nitschinger.at/Writing-a-simple-lexer-in-PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string in your example is almost a valid JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) structure!

**Here's what your string would look like as valid JSON**

```
 {
    "maxWidth": 800,
    "openEffect": "elastic",
    "closeEffect": "elastic",
    "helpers": {
        "title": {
            "type": "outside"
        },
        "thumbs": {
            "width": 50,
            "height": 50
        }
    }
}
```

So our approach (as suggested by @WiseGuy) would be to first inject a few characters with `preg_replace` to **Turn your string init into valid JSON:**

```
$str = preg_replace('/\b/' , '"' , $str);
$str = '{'  . $str . '}';
```

The regex above is using the `Word Boundaries` anchor to add quotation marks around all words. Then we wrap the whole thing in curly braces and voilà, we've got a x-language compatible object format.

**We can now use a standard function to produce our object:**

```
$objUserConfig = json_decode($str, true);
```

A good beginners tutorial on JSON here: http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/an-introduction-to-json

Use a linter tool such as http://jsonlint.com/ to validate JSON. I used it to debug your example and convert it into proper JSON for my example.

Comment: @Wiseguy You are awesome. Thank you very much. Add it as an answer so that i can mark it as accepted.

Comment: Since @Martin's explanation was already down this path, I just figured he could use it to expand his answer. Feel free to copy/edit it in the text of your answer as a permanent reference for when that link dies.

Comment: @MartinJoiner Thanks for the answer. I am familiar with JSON. The input will be from normal user so i want to keep it simple. There is minimum chance that the normal user will enter a valid JSON. Add WiseGuy response to expand your answer if possible.

Comment: I have expanded my answer now using @WiseGuy's solution.  Sorry for delay, it was end of day when I posted yesterday so I shutdown just after.

Answer (score 1):

Your input string looks like a json format. PHP has `json_decode()` to convert json string to object.

To convert to array, use below code:

```
json_decode($jsonStr, true);
```

Refer: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: It _looks_ a bit like it, but is _not_ valid JSON! Providing an answer that suggests passing invalid JSON into a function that requires valid JSON is not helpful. Only people who did not need to ask the question would understand your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am familiar with JSON. The input will be from normal user so i want to keep it simple. There is minimum chance that the normal user will enter a valid JSON. @WiseGuy comment did the trick http://ideone.com/WixBF8

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I know you are showing the printed output of an array and
not a static representation of a php declared array. This is just an
example of how you might convert it into something that can be parsed
into that array. If php has that ability to do so dynamically (I don't know).

Convert the file, read in $str

In this order, do regex on $str.
Each is global flag.

`(?i)([a-z]+)` to `'$1'`
`(?i)(?<=[a-z]')\s*:(?=\s*[^{\s])` to `=>`
`(?i)(?<=[a-z]')\s*:\s*{` to `=> array(`
`}` to `)`

Finally, `$newstr = "array(\n$str\n)"`
However, something like this that can be read by a php parser as a static
array. How it gets dynamically interpreted into vars I don't know.
Perl can do this.